# Using a Template Variable in a Model

Tags: channel-entries, template-partials

I'd like to use a template variable {product_minimum_order_value} in a product model. Channel fields are accessible in template code using {django_syntax}, however I would like to use them in the models without sending them as form data.

Is Expression Engine able to do this without relying on the horrific mess of an alternative I've posted below:

```
SELECT title, field_id_118
AS 'product_minimum_order_value'
FROM exp_channel_titles t
INNER JOIN exp_channel_data d
ON d.entry_id = t.entry_id
WHERE d.entry_id = 82;`
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a model (Any backend PHP file). You can do something like,

```
$data = ee('Model')->get('ChannelEntry', "82")->fields('title', 'field_id_118')->first();
$product_minimum_order_value = "";
if($data)
{
    $product_minimum_order_value = $data->field_id_118;
    unset($data);
}
```